# Convert mongo request with MongoTemplate (spring)

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I would like to convert a part of this mongodb request:

```
{
        "$group": {
                "_id": {
                        "instrument_name": "$instrument_name",
                        "interval":{  
                             "$minute":{  
                                    $add:[new Date("1970-01-01"), "$date"]
                             }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

With the aggregate method from MongoTemplate (with spring).

My problem is with the interval property. I would like return a list of instruments by an time interval of one minute.

I tried many solutions, but I can't resolve the part:

```
                            "interval":{  
                             "$minute":{  
                                    $add:[new Date("1970-01-01"), "$date"]
                             }
                        }



Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("instrument_name").in(instruments)),
        Aggregation.group("instrumentName", ???)),
        Aggregation.project().andExpression("instrumentName").as("instrument_name")
    );
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try projecting the interval field first by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** in the projection operation and then group by the new fields in the group operation:

```
// define epochDate here e.g DateTime epochDate = ...
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("instrument_name").in(instruments)),
    project("instrument_name").and("date").plus(epochDate).as("interval"), 
    group(fields().and("instrument_name").and("interval")).count().as("count")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we can optimize this:

```
TypedAggregation<InstrumentModel> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(InstrumentModel.class,
        Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("instrument_name").in(instruments)),
        Aggregation.project().and("instrumentName").as("instrument_name").and("time").plus(epoch).extractMinute().as("interval"),
        Aggregation.group(Fields.fields().and("instrument_name").and("interval")).count().as("ticks")
    );
```

But it works